# [Python]how can i sort the list nested tuple by asc order/ desc order?

Tags: python, list, sorting

first of all, i'm not English native speaker. so my sentences may be wired. please understand me!

Anyway, while I do my homework, i have to re-order the list nested with tuple by asc/desc order.
my list is like this:

```
lst=[(a,30),(b,80),(c,180),(d,200),(e,90),(f,1200),(g,120),(h,920),(i,7)]
```

and i want to make that list to like this:

```
desc_lst=[(f,1200),(h,920),(d,200),(c,180),(g,120),(e,90),(b,80),(a,30),(i,7)]
```

and

```
asc_list=[(i,7),(a,30),(b,80),(e,90),(g,120),(c,180),(d,200),(h,920),(f,1200)].
```

how can i sort this?
i can sort just normal list, for example lst=[1,2,3,4,9,8,5]. but in this case,i can't sort these because the list has tuple as an element. please answer...! ipy bless you and your family!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
lst = [('a', 30), ('b', 80), ('c', 180), ('d', 200), ('e', 90), ('f', 1200), ('g', 120), ('h', 920), ('i', 7)]
print(sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))
```

With the output result being

```
[('f', 1200), ('h', 920), ('d', 200), ('c', 180), ('g', 120), ('e', 90), ('b', 80), ('a', 30), ('i', 7)]
```